# Language change on website best way

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am making a website where I need to include a language change button from Hungarian to English. 
Now my question is which is the best way to do that. 
I mean should I just make new HTML files with different language or is there a better way to do it. I found some solution with Javascript but they used blocks which is not good for me because I have to change a lot of texts and some PHP solution but I have never used PHP yet.
Best would be a solution with Javascript or Node.js or something that I can learn fast :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dump all the content of the page to a string or some data structure and then by using the module "translate" you can translate it to any other language. It provides translation to multiple languages then on button click translate the text and send back as response and set the text on the client side. You can install it by:-

```
 npm install --save translate
```

A sample code for that will be:-

```
// 'es' can be a language string or an object like { to: 'es' }
translate('Hello world', 'es').then(text => {
console.log(text);  // Hola mundo
});
```

You can find more help here:-

```
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/translate
```

Comment: I am glad, it helped.